# Listview doesn't appear if not declared into onCreate

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to populate a listView, but if I initialize it after `onCreate` it doesn't appear. I tried to initialize it into the `onCreate` and use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after I insert values into my String array used to populate the listView but I have no success.

Does someone know how to solve this problem? I checked other questions but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the Activity you’re using?

Comment: Provide some code so that we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the UI thread.

Also it's better to use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of a `String[]`

Keep references to both the `ArrayList` and `ArrayAdapter` inside your `activity` class.

```
private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Initialize your `ArrayList<String>` and set `adapter` in your `onCreate`

```
items = new ArrayList<String>();
// add initial items
items.add("1st item");
// create adapter
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
// set the adapter
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now whenever you want to change the items, call the `add()`, `remove()`, etc methods of the `ArrayList` and subsequently call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. The change to the `ArrayList` can be done in any thread, but `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` should be called in UI thread.

For example in a button press you might wanna do

```
items.add("New item");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also you might wanna check these:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example) and

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964768/arrayadapter-remove-by-index)

PS: Sorry for my bad posting skills. I'm new.